# Как сделать запрос на сервер для получения данных в react через useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Есть бекенд, необходимо необходимо получить данные из него, для получения информации с него необходимо отправить запрос в виде

```
  "datetime_from": "*",   "datetime_to": "*", "instrument_ticker": "*", "strategy_code": "*", "broker_token": "*"
```

Как сделать так чтобы при выполнении useEffect отпралял данные на сервер

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch('localhost:8000/prices')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => setData(json))
}, [])
return (
     <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>
```

Никак не могу разобраться как отправить Get запрос в виде json на сервер

Comment: А сейчас что не работает? Укажите с протоколом, `http://localhost:8000/prices`

Comment: Дело в том, для того чтобы получить данные с сервера необходимо отправить данные (  "datetime_from": "*",   "datetime_to": "*", "instrument_ticker": "*", "strategy_code": "*", "broker_token": "*") на сервер, тоесть выборка

Comment: Если я делаю это через Postman, то выбираю Get запрос, указываю адрес и в поле Raw ввожу json код, сервер на это присылает ответ, вопрос как сделать тоже самое в React

Comment: 'localhost:8000/prices' это еше что?? запросы делаются так /yourApi/prices и в итоге запрос идет так твой локалхост или адрес/yourApi/prices

Comment: открой f12 -> network и там увидеш как идут запросы, куда идут, с чем идут и что приходит